# Parsing data rows in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle10g, resultset

This is quite clumsy.

*Initial info:* There's a clumsy select query eventually returning 0 or 1 depending on several conditions. Usually it get's to select only one row (other data is cut of by where, etc.). The problem occurs when there's more rows to parse. So the data actually looks like follows:

```
Status
0
1
```

instead of

```
Status
1
```

*Problem:* Only one rowed data is needed in return, i.e. if there's a 1 present in any row, it should 1 returned, otherwise 0.

*Condition:* It should be done only in a query (no variables, ifs etc.).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that 1 and 0 are the only valuesbeing returned, Can't you use a max over this query to see any 1s..?

```
select max(id) result
  from (
  select 1 id from dual
  union all
  select 0 id from dual
)

    RESULT
----------
         1

  1  select max(id)
  2    from (
  3    select 0 id from dual
  4    union all
  5    select 0 id from dual
  6    union all
  7    select 0 id from dual
  8* )
SQL> /

   MAX(ID)
----------
         0
```

Comment: It's a paragraph of sql there, who new max could save me!? :)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. Otherwise I wouldn't come here. :) Thanks btw.